# indexing version numbers in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Say my documents have a field, called "app_version".
That field is a string of the type: "1.16.21"

I'd like to index it so I can search for versions within a range.

How should I do that?

Note that "1.13.5">"1.7.21" unlike a lexicographic ordering might mean (comparing strings).

Comment: Use a `transform` to compute a number out of that string, tokenizing (in Groovy) the string at `.`. Something like: 1 * 1000 + 16 * 100 + 21 and then comparing the actual numbers.

Comment: That's one way to do that.
But I'd like to still see the original version number as well.

Comment: You index one `string` field with the `.` notation and use an additional field, or a sub-field to index the numeric version.